# Laravel policies: no usages in project, only 403

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I am trying to use laravel policies to check if a story is "visible" and if it isn't, if the authenticated user ownes the story (in which case he can still view it). I set up my policy using

```
php artisan make:policy StoryPolicy --model=Story
```

There I set up the checks required to see if the authenticated user can see the Story or not

```php
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\User;
use App\Story;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class StoryPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view the story.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Story  $story
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function view(User $user, Story $story)
    {
        if ($story->visibility == 'visible') {
            return true;
        } else {
            return $story->user_id == $user->id;
        }
    }
}
```

I register the policy in my AuthServiceProvider

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        'App\Story' => 'App\Policies\StoryPolicy'
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
    }
}
```

As I understand it, I should be able to use this policy in my controller. That is what I did.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Storyblock;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Category;
use App\Story;

class StoryController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('auth')->except('show');
    }

    //  GET shows the story page
    public function show(Story $story) {
        $this->authorize('view',$story);

        return view('story.show', compact('story'));
    }

}
```

this however always result in a 403

I've tried many things, changing up the way the policies are set, changing the logic dd'ing if all is correct. After 4 hours of lookign online I failed to come up with an answer.

Also, in my phpStorm I noticed that my policy files are indicated red with no usages over the entire project. This makes me think that I somehow fail to import them in my AuthServiceProvider

Comment: this is when you can ignore what your IDE says, there is a lot it can't know without run time information, especially considering the only references to Policy classes is via strings

Answer (score 0):

i don't see all your code but you get this message when you want to access of lavarel resouce and you don't have the scrf token make sure all your view or on the app view header you have this

```
<!-- CSRF Token -->
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

i think you just try to get a resource without this then it just tell you don't have access of this one.

Comment: Have it in my layouts/master which the view extends so it's not that

Answer (score 0):

You have specified that the `show` method isn't going to have the `auth` middleware assigned, so there may not be an authenticated User. From the Policy documentation:

> "By default, all gates and policies automatically return false if the incoming HTTP request was not initiated by an authenticated user"

You will need to continue reading the Policy documentation for how to handle the lack of an authenticated user, guest.

[Laravel 5.7 Docs - Authorization - Writing Policies - Guest Users](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization#guest-users)

Comment: I always tested it with an authenticated user tho, but I will look into this, thanks!